# метод soup.find не находит некоторые строки html кода

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# константы
URL = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Fracture%20Case'

#получение html кода
def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(URL)
    return r

#получение контента
def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')
    #block = soup.find('div', class_='market_commodity_order_summary').find('span')
    block = soup.find(id = 'market_commodity_forsale')
    return block

HTML = get_html(URL)
info = get_content(HTML)
print(info)
```

это получаю на выходе:

```
<div class="market_commodity_order_summary" id="market_commodity_forsale">
</div>
```

а вот что я бы хотел получить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка в том, что `soup.find(id = 'market_commodity_forsale')` не верно. Попробуйте изменить эту строчку на `soup.find( 'div' ,{ 'id' : 'market_commodity_forsale' })`

Comment: и правда! Именно в этом ошибка!